# Apache logs on Debian GNU/Linux shows windows executable files

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, logwatch

I use logwatch to watch my server logs. It shows this in httpd log section:

```
19033 Windows executable files (502.53 MB)
```

This is a Debian GNU/Linux server. So it shouldn't be any Windows executables. I couldn't find any neither. Is this some kind of mixup or there is something I'm missing?

All I could find in the logs are these lines:

```
[Sat Dec 11 22:13:00 2010] [error] [client 89.6.249.126] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/perl.exe
[Sat Dec 11 22:13:01 2010] [error] [client 89.6.249.126] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rguest.exe
[Sat Dec 11 22:13:10 2010] [error] [client 89.6.249.126] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/get32.exe
[Sun May 22 02:25:16 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /_mem_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:16 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /_mem_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:17 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /_vti_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:18 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /_vti_bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:26 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:29 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe /c+dir?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:35 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /bin/scripts/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:38 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /cgi-bin/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:25:56 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ceilidh.exe
[Sun May 22 02:25:57 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/Cgitest.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:02 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/cgimail.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:09 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/cmd.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:11 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dbmlparser.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:26 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/fpcount.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:28 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/fpexplorer.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:29 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/get32.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:30 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/get32.exe\\dir
[Sun May 22 02:26:33 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/htimage.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:36 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/fpexplore.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:42 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/imagemap.exe
[Sun May 22 02:26:51 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailform.exe
[Sun May 22 02:27:11 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/perl.exe
[Sun May 22 02:27:31 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ppdscgi.exe
[Sun May 22 02:27:52 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rguest.exe
[Sun May 22 02:28:26 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/visadmin.exe
[Sun May 22 02:28:27 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/visitor.exe
[Sun May 22 02:29:18 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] File does not exist: /home/gg/www/cmd.exe
[Sun May 22 02:29:46 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/visadmin.exe
[Sun May 22 02:30:12 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /msadc/../../../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir%20c:\\ HTTP/1.0
[Sun May 22 02:31:00 2011] [error] [client 2.119.20.33] Invalid URI in request GET /scripts/../../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply "someone" tried to access those files via URL. Actually, it's probably an automated script looking for usable exploits.

While those particular request are obviously targeted at Windows systems, I suggest you to install and configure apache module `mod_security` to catch and block those requests (and those targeted to linux system, too!).

**EDIT**

Actually, what's strange is that `logwatch` says **19033** files, which seems not to correspond on your logs.

Also, for 404/500 and similar erros should report something like:

```
--------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------ 

Requests with error response codes
404 Not Found
   /favicon.ico: 2 Time(s) 
500 Internal Server Error
   /: 1 Time(s)
---------------------- httpd End -------------------------
```

**Maybe** `logwatch` interprets as Windows executables *other extension* and not only `.exe` files.

Comment: Thanks. My concern is how a simple 404 can cause 502.53 MB bandwith? Or there is really some "executable" file (I couldn't cacth) served?

Comment: Seems you have very frequent requests for those files. Let's say one request generate 250 bytes, you need 2M requests to have 500Mb. If you have one request every 5 second, it take only 4 mounths to reach 500Mb.

Comment: Well, then there is a problem with logwatch. AFAIK these are daily logs. Here are last 3 days: Feb 21 - 12299 Windows executable files (339.63 MB), Feb 22 - 9247 Windows executable files (257.49 MB), Feb 23 - 20074 Windows executable files (559.11 MB)

Comment: That's what I thought. But couldn't be sure. There are cache files with simple html in them, with no extension. Only explanation I can think of is them. As for errors yes there are other errors. 400, 401, 403, 404, 405 and 416. But I don't think those are the reason.